# apply formula for certain columns using other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame

```
  dat = data.frame(Type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D"), NextType = c("A", "B","B", "C","C","D",NA), 
                 A = c(rep(0,7)), 
                 B = rep(0,7), 
                 C = rep(0,7) , 
                 D = rep(0,7),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
dat

 Type NextType A B C D
1    A        A 0 0 0 0
2    A        B 0 0 0 0
3    B        B 0 0 0 0
4    B        C 0 0 0 0
5    C        C 0 0 0 0
6    C        D 0 0 0 0
7    D     <NA> 0 0 0 0
```

What's the best way to populate columns A, B and C and D with a 1 if the column name (A, B, C, D etc...) = Type  = NextType

so

```
column A would be 1,0,0,0,0,0,0
column B would be 0,0,1,0,0,0,0
column C would be 0,0,0,0,1,0,0
column D would be 0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

NOTE -- THIS HAS TO BE DYNAMIC. I have 4 columns above A, B  and C and D but there can be 10, 20 or any number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);

dat %>% 
    select(Type, NextType) %>% 
    mutate(key = if_else(Type == NextType & !is.na(Type) & !is.na(NextType), Type, "other"), 
           val = 1) %>% 
    spread(key, val, fill = 0) %>% 
    select(-other)

#  Type NextType A B C
#1    A        A 1 0 0
#2    A        B 0 0 0
#3    B        B 0 1 0
#4    B        C 0 0 0
#5    C        C 0 0 1
#6    C     <NA> 0 0 0
```

*Data*:

```
dat = data.frame(Type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), NextType = c("A", "B","B", "C","C",NA), A = c(rep(0,6)), B = rep(0,6), C = rep(0,6) , stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Sorry I left out the case when there is no match at all. Can you see edit?

Comment: So you want a column that is exclusively zero?

Comment: You could try `model.matrix` in this case, create a key column of factor type that has the same levels as the `Type` column + other, and `model.matrix` will keep the extra levels that are missing. `dat %>% select(Type, NextType) %>% mutate(key = factor(if_else(Type == NextType & !is.na(Type) & !is.na(NextType), Type, "other"), levels = c("other", unique(Type)))) %>% bind_cols(., as.data.frame(model.matrix(~ key - 1, .))) %>% select(-keyother, -key)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat = data.frame(Type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), NextType = c("A", "B","B", "C","C",NA))
dat <- dat %>% mutate(A=ifelse(Type == NextType & Type == 'A', 1, 0),B=ifelse(Type == NextType & Type == 'B', 1, 0),C=ifelse(Type == NextType & Type == 'C', 1, 0))
```

Comment: thanks but it needs to be dynamic to handle any number of columns

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `model.matrix`, `diff`, and `apply`.

```
cbind(dat[1], apply(model.matrix(~Type-1, dat), 2, function(x) c(x[1], diff(x) > 0)))
```

`model.matrix(~Type-1, dat)` returns a matrix of dummy variables where each column is 1 when the corresponding value is present in the column. This is fed to `apply` which takes each column and returns the first value of the column as well as an evaluation of whether the difference is greater than 0. The resulting matrix is combined with the first column using `cbind`.

which returns

```
  Type TypeA TypeB TypeC
1    A     1     0     0
2    A     0     0     0
3    B     0     1     0
4    B     0     0     0
5    C     0     0     1
6    C     0     0     0
```

If you wish to include the second column as well, change `df[1]` to `df[1:2]`.

---

An alternative base R method using `lapply` is

```
dat[, LETTERS[1:3]] <- lapply(unique(dat$Type),
                              function(x) (dat$Type == x) * !duplicated(dat$Type))
```

Here, we cycle through the unique values of dat$Type and check whether each element of dat$Type is equal to this value and if the element is a duplicate. This returns a list which is assigned to corresponding variables in dat.

Answer (score 0):

with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(Type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), NextType = c("A", "B","B", "C","C",NA), 
             A = c(rep(0,6)), B = rep(0,6), C = rep(0,6) )
dat

dat[Type=="A", A:=(Type == NextType)]
dat[Type=="B", B:=(Type == NextType)]
dat[Type=="C", C:=(Type == NextType)]
```

**EDIT**

Dynamic (probably not very efficient, maybe someone has other suggestions?)

```
mycols <- names(dat)[!(names(dat) %in% c("Type", "NextType"))]
for(i in mycols){
  dat[Type==i, (i) := (Type==NextType)]
}
```

Comment: can you make it dynamic for any number of columns see edit

Comment: see edit. it does what you want. not sure how efficiently